# What is the logic behind the number of views of the puzzles?

Tags: support, questions

After about a year on SE, I have noticed that the number of views for any puzzle range dramatically from less than 100 to 5K or more. I assume a puzzle is considered viewed when a reader clicks on it? So what makes someone click on a particular puzzle? The puzzles that get over 1K views: Are they viewed because some other sites catch them? Or is it just word of mouth? Are there puzzle solving groups that spread the word about a good puzzle?

Comment: I think it's mostly because of the "Hot Network Questions" that promote puzzles over all 171 Stack Exchange sites. Unfortunately I don't know how these are selected. It seems like many first posts of new members get there, probably to keep them on this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Logic? What logic?

I don't think anybody (except maybe some SEO experts at Google and similar companies?) really understands what makes some questions more clicked than others. Some factors include:

- **Hot Network Questions.** If a question hits the [HNQ list](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot), it gets featured on the sidebar of all pages on all SE sites, for as long as it's on the list (usually a few days at most) - such questions often skyrocket in views and votes.

  The algorithm used to determine "hotness" is [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/61343/278659).
- **Common/popular search results.** Some questions get incredible numbers of views without ever being featured on the HNQ list, so there must be other factors involved.

  [This question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/9979/5373) is the second most-viewed on the entire site, despite being closed and therefore not eligible for the HNQ list. Ditto [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/49410/5373), which also makes it into the top ten despite its negative score. [This question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/17681/5373) probably did go HNQ, but it's had at least 50,000 more views since then. I guess their titles must be things that people Google for a lot?
- > Are they viewed because some other sites catch them? Or is it just word of mouth? Are there puzzle solving groups that spread the word about a good puzzle?

  And yes, all of these are probably factors too, at least for some puzzles.

But at the end of the day, there's a hell of a lot of chance involved in all of these factors. Whether or not a question goes HNQ depends on it getting either lots of answers, or lots of votes on a single answer, quickly. This doesn't always reflect the quality of the Q&A (in fact, sometimes it does the opposite!) And SEO probably (?) depends on having commonly searched-for titles, but overly generic titles should probably be changed to something more descriptive, and if they're *too* generic they won't be good for SEO anyway.

So, in the words of George RR Martin, **who the hell knows**.

Comment: That [formula for the HNQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/61343/374482) explains why overly broad questions that generate many answers in short time are by far more likely to get into HNQ than just _good_ questions.

Comment: @A.P. Yup, exactly.