# Do views equal viewers?

Tags: support

Although the following question appears related, it does not answer my specific question. [What is the logic behind the number of views of the puzzles?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6176/what-is-the-logic-behind-the-number-of-views-of-the-puzzles)

---

**Question**

If a question has "30 views", does it mean that 30 different users have viewed it or could it mean that, for example, 1 user viewed it 30 times?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, if a user visits the page and visits it again at least 15 minutes later, that counts as a second view. A third visit, at least 15 minutes later than the second view, will count as a third one and so on.

More details here on Meta Stack Exchange: [How are the number of views in a question calculated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/36728/295232)